# How to slide a view from one view to other

Tags: android

I have three linear layouts with horizontal orientation. Inside that three views are placed its kind of 3X3 grid of view. layout xml is as follows

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_h1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view_00"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/round_rectangle_bg" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view_01"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/round_rectangle_bg" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view_02"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/round_rectangle_bg" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_h2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view_10"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/round_rectangle_bg_filled" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view_11"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/round_rectangle_bg" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view_12"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/round_rectangle_bg" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_h3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view_20"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/round_rectangle_bg" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view_21"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/round_rectangle_bg" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view_22"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/round_rectangle_bg" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

i want to move view_10 to view_12 how to achieve that?? basically need to slide any view vertically and horizontally and maintain filled view state.

Comment: share your expected output

Comment: Why not use a [`View Pager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) for horizontal slide.

Answer (score 1):

This answer may help you. I think it is better perform this task with recyclerview with grid layout manager. from the recycle view you can swipe views and can interchange them.

first of all add dependency for the the recycle view and card view to your build gradle

```
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25+'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25+'
```

Add dependency according to the project SDK version, I have 25, So that I have added25+

Now create the activity,

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Context mContext;

```
RelativeLayout mRelativeLayout;
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;

private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Get the application context
    mContext = getApplicationContext();

    // Get the widgets reference from XML layout
    mRelativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_main);
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

    // Initialize a new String array
    String[] animals = {
            "Aardvark",
            "Albatross",
            "Alligator",
            "Alpaca",
            "Ant",
            "Anteater",
            "Antelope",
            "Ape",
            "Armadillo",
            "Donkey",
            "Baboon",
            "Badger",
            "Barracuda",
            "Bear",
            "Beaver",
            "Bee"
    };

    /*
        GridLayoutManager
            A RecyclerView.LayoutManager implementations that lays out items in a grid.
            By default, each item occupies 1 span. You can change it by providing a custom
            GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup instance via setSpanSizeLookup(SpanSizeLookup).
    */
    /*
        public GridLayoutManager (Context context, int spanCount)
            Creates a vertical GridLayoutManager

        Parameters
            context : Current context, will be used to access resources.
            spanCount : The number of columns in the grid
    */
    // Define a layout for RecyclerView
    mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(mContext,3);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

    // Initialize a new instance of RecyclerView Adapter instance
    mAdapter = new AnimalsAdapter(mContext,animals);

    // Set the adapter for RecyclerView
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    setUpItemTouchHelper(); // this method is use to swipe views
}
```

Create the Layouts for the class. Add recyclerview to the main layout

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.crowderia.myapplication.MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        >
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Then add carview for the grid custom_view.xml, This card view act as a item of the grid.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
    card_view:cardMaxElevation="4dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="2dp"
    card_view:contentPadding="5dp"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="3dp"
        >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Create the adaptor for the gridlayout.

```
public class AnimalsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AnimalsAdapter.ViewHolder>{

private String[] mDataSet;
private Context mContext;
private Random mRandom = new Random();

public AnimalsAdapter(Context context, String[] DataSet){
    mDataSet = DataSet;
    mContext = context;
}

@Override
public AnimalsAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType){
    // Create a new View
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.custom_view,parent,false);
    ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
    return vh;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position){
    holder.mTextView.setText(mDataSet[position]);
```

//         Generate a random color
        int color = getRandomHSVColor();

```
    // Set a random color for TextView background
    holder.mTextView.setBackgroundColor(getLighterColor(color));

    // Set a text color for TextView
    holder.mTextView.setTextColor(getReverseColor(color));

    // Set a gradient background for LinearLayout
    holder.mLinearLayout.setBackground(getGradientDrawable());

    // Emboss the TextView text
    applyEmbossMaskFilter(holder.mTextView);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount(){
    return mDataSet.length;
}

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    public TextView mTextView;
    public LinearLayout mLinearLayout;
    public ViewHolder(View v){
        super(v);
        mTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv);
        mLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.ll);
    }
}

// Custom method to apply emboss mask filter to TextView
protected void applyEmbossMaskFilter(TextView tv){
    EmbossMaskFilter embossFilter = new EmbossMaskFilter(
            new float[]{1f, 5f, 1f}, // direction of the light source
            0.8f, // ambient light between 0 to 1
            8, // specular highlights
            7f // blur before applying lighting
    );
    tv.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE,null);
    tv.getPaint().setMaskFilter(embossFilter);
}

// Custom method to generate random HSV color
protected int getRandomHSVColor(){
    // Generate a random hue value between 0 to 360
    int hue = mRandom.nextInt(361);
    // We make the color depth full
    float saturation = 1.0f;
    // We make a full bright color
    float value = 1.0f;
    // We avoid color transparency
    int alpha = 255;
    // Finally, generate the color
    int color = Color.HSVToColor(alpha, new float[]{hue, saturation, value});
    // Return the color
    return color;
}

// Custom method to create a GradientDrawable object
protected GradientDrawable getGradientDrawable(){
    GradientDrawable gradient = new GradientDrawable();
    gradient.setGradientType(GradientDrawable.SWEEP_GRADIENT);
    gradient.setColors(new int[]{getRandomHSVColor(), getRandomHSVColor(),getRandomHSVColor()});
    return gradient;
}

// Custom method to get a darker color
protected int getDarkerColor(int color){
    float[] hsv = new float[3];
    Color.colorToHSV(color, hsv);
    hsv[2] = 0.8f *hsv[2];
    return Color.HSVToColor(hsv);
}

// Custom method to get a lighter color
protected int getLighterColor(int color){
    float[] hsv = new float[3];
    Color.colorToHSV(color,hsv);
    hsv[2] = 0.2f + 0.8f * hsv[2];
    return Color.HSVToColor(hsv);
}

// Custom method to get reverse color
protected int getReverseColor(int color){
    float[] hsv = new float[3];
    Color.RGBToHSV(
            Color.red(color), // Red value
            Color.green(color), // Green value
            Color.blue(color), // Blue value
            hsv
    );
    hsv[0] = (hsv[0] + 180) % 360;
    return Color.HSVToColor(hsv);
}
```

And the most important part is the OnItemTouchHelper method. Create a method in main activity and copy this code into it.

```
    ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback simpleItemTouchCallback = new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT|ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT|ItemTouchHelper.UP|ItemTouchHelper.DOWN) {

            // not important, we don't want drag & drop
            @Override
            public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
                return false;
            }


            @Override
            public int getSwipeDirs(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
                int position = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
                AnimalsAdapter mAdapter = (AnimalsAdapter) recyclerView.getAdapter();
                return super.getSwipeDirs(recyclerView, viewHolder);
            }

            @Override
            public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int swipeDir) {
                int swipedPosition = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
                AnimalsAdapter mAdapter = (AnimalsAdapter) mRecyclerView.getAdapter();
                if (swipeDir == ItemTouchHelper.LEFT){
//                    mAdapter.pendingRemoval(swipedPosition);
                } else if (swipeDir == ItemTouchHelper.UP){
//                    mAdapter.pendingAccept(swipedPosition);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildDraw(Canvas c, RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, float dX, float dY, int actionState, boolean isCurrentlyActive) {
                View itemView = viewHolder.itemView;

                // not sure why, but this method get's called for viewholder that are already swiped away
                if (viewHolder.getAdapterPosition() == -1) {
                    // not interested in those
                    return;
                }



                super.onChildDraw(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, dX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive);
            }
        };
        ItemTouchHelper mItemTouchHelper = new ItemTouchHelper(simpleItemTouchCallback);
        mItemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(mRecyclerView);
```

you can catch the swipe action in onSwiped method and perform action, Write code to to change the carview position there, You can call to adaptor on that postition and change the adaptor cards, Use notify.. methods to refrech the adaptor. for more details read the [RecylerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) documentation and [RecylerView adaptor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html) documentations.

Cheers!!!